# When change the angular template nswag generated file return result key word not considering

Tags: c#, angular, nswag, metronic

I try to move one angular template to another angular template. after moved i run the nswag file then i run the application. data not mapping because return result contain result keyword but nswag generated file not considering result keyword. i modified nswag generated service-proxy _data.result then only its worked
C# file return result defined

```
{
  "pastRecords": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-30T04:47:05.350Z",
      "value": {}
    }
  ],
  "futureRecords": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-30T04:47:05.350Z",
      "value": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

but it's returning

```
{
  "result": {
    "pastRecords": [
      {
     "date": "2020-01-30T04:47:05.350Z",
      "value": {}
      }
  ],
  "futureRecords": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-30T04:47:05.350Z",
      "value": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

previous template defined _data only but its works but new template expecting _data.result

```
init(_data?: any) {
    if (_data) {
        if (Array.isArray(_data["pastRecords"])) {
            this.pastRecords = [] as any;
            for (let item of _data["pastRecords"])
                this.pastRecords.push(ChartSingleResultDto.fromJS(item));
        }
        if (Array.isArray(_data["futureRecords"])) {
            this.futureRecords = [] as any;
            for (let item of _data["futureRecords"])
                this.futureRecords.push(ChartSingleResultDto.fromJS(item));
        }
    }
}
```

this one works previous template but new template expecting

```
init(_data?: any) {
    if (_data) {
        if (Array.isArray(_data.result["pastRecords"])) {
            this.pastRecords = [] as any;
            for (let item of _data.result["pastRecords"])
                this.pastRecords.push(ChartSingleResultDto.fromJS(item));
        }
        if (Array.isArray(_data.result["futureRecords"])) {
            this.futureRecords = [] as any;
            for (let item of _data.result["futureRecords"])
                this.futureRecords.push(ChartSingleResultDto.fromJS(item));
        }
    }
}
```